# BOSH: Manually set director_uuid in deployment manifest

Tags: manifest, cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I am performing the tutorial [learn bosh](https://mariash.github.io/learn-bosh) and got a question concerning step [Set Deployment Manifest](https://mariash.github.io/learn-bosh/#set_manifest).

Why do I have to set the `director_uuid` manually in the deployment manifest (which I then upload to the very same director)? Is this a security feature?

Comment: It may be to prevent accidentally deploying to the wrong bosh environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the document, `director_uuid` is for CLI to operate target Director.

> Deployment Identification
>
> name [String, required]: The name of the deployment. A single Director
>   can manage multiple deployments and distinguishes them by name.
>
> director_uuid [String, required]: This string must match the UUID of
>   the currently targeted Director for the CLI to allow any operations on
>   the deployment. Use bosh status to display the UUID of the currently
>   targeted Director.

Refer to: [BOSH documentation](https://bosh.io/docs/deployment-manifest.html#deployment)

Cloud Foundry can provide Cloud Service like PaaS. If you deploy a manifest to the wrong environment that means your customer's environment could break down.
That complicated parameter helps you to avoid miss operation in your operational environment.